# Statistics on the site's development

Tags: discussion, beta

I noticed the other day that at the [Area 51 page for the Linguistics site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6673/linguistics), there is a little summary of some statistical measures of the site so far, along with the "good" and "not so good" values for those measures.  I'm not sure how many other people were aware of that page, so I wanted to publicize it here.  It can help us keep track of our site's progress and make sure that it continues to develop well (as measured by the Stack Exchange folks).  We're currently doing pretty well, it looks like, so let's keep it up.  :)

Comment: We'll we need more people. There might be a slowly increasing influx thanks to links from, for instance, Google but it doesn't hurt to shout from the rooftops for a little while :)

Comment: For details on interpreting these numbers, see: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/does-this-site-have-a-chance-of-succeeding/

Answer (score 3):

Traditionally beta sites (and most sites altogether) have no problem with '%questions answered' or ' answers per question'. The main difficulty are the other three.

'questions per day' and 'visits per day' are increased by advertising (a good, popular question in the StackExchange what-do-you-call-it 'most popular question' can do it).

But the '#avid users' is only really made by **voting as much you can**.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I've been looking at those stats now and then.

Some paramaters "*need some work*", using the stats words :) but it's also true that we are in a good position. If we keep growing like this, the site will be healthy.